# Can someone explain EOS sidechains to me?

Tags: smart-contract, dapp, sidechain, mainchain

[image]

Independent platform, Main chain, sidechains, smart contracts.

Can someone define these terms for me?

I don't quite understand the idea of sidechains. Is sidechains something like threads in parallel computation? Partitioning of computational power? And do they have the same block intervals?

Dapps, or smart contracts, can run in one or more sidechains?

Answer (score 2):

> Sidechaining is any mechanism that allows tokens from one blockchain to be securely used within a completely separate blockchain but still moved back to the original chain if necessary. By convention the original chain is normally referred to as the "main chain", while any additional blockchains which allow users to transact within them in the tokens of the main chain are referred to as "sidechains".

Source: [What is a sidechain?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/379/what-is-a-sidechain)

Found you a good video explaining what a smart contract is: [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZE2HxTmxfrI)

Comment: Dan has previously stated that a side chain transaction would consume a 10:1 amount of resources to process on the main chain, so with 100 IBC tx/s there would effectively be 1,000 tx/s needed on the main net.  This does not seem scalable as the main net could easily become more congested.  Is multi-threading needed to accomplish this?  Are there details that I'm missing or misinterpreting?

Answer (score 1):

This video by EOS BlockSmith helped clear somethings up for me:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tADNG7smI8w